# Query two same column

Tags: sql, sqlite

is it possible to query in this way like 'OR' function.

Updated example:

```
Select S.*, U.* from Staff S, Unit U where S.Unit='' OR S.Unit= U.UnitCode;
```

Staff Table Schema:

```
Staff ID, Staff Name, UnitCode, StaffNumber
```

Unit Schema:

```
UnitCode, ClassCode
```

The above updated example works. But the staff records whom unit is blank will be duplicated with all the unit codes.

For example of results output:

```
Staff ID     Staff Name     UnitCode     ClassCode    Staff Number
1            John            IT1         B123         234
2            Sally           BUS2        B234         0589
3            Johnson         IT1         B123          111
4            Johnson         BUS2        B234          111
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "Unit as blank OR Unit matches with staff"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SQLite, Use `OR` instead of `||`

```
Select S.*, U.* 
from Staff S, Unit U 
where S.Unit = '' OR S.Unit= U.UnitCode;
```

What is the result if I removed this condition? `S.Unit = ''`

```
Select S.*, U.* 
from Staff S INNER JOIN Unit U 
         on S.Unit = U.UnitCode;
```

**UPDATE 1**

can you try this one?

```
SELECT x.*
FROM Staff x INNER JOIN
    (Select DISTINCT S.StaffID
     from Staff S INNER JOIN Unit U 
             on (S.Unit = U.UnitCode) OR
                (S.Unit = '')
     ) y ON x.StaffID = y.StaffID
```

Comment: @toteski, if i do it in this way.. the null records will be duplicated with all the unit names and such. How can I resolve it ?

Comment: i can help you more if you could post the schema or even some dummy records so i can tell why there are duplicate records in the result :)

Comment: thank you.. what if i removed this condition `S.Unit = ''`? what would be the output then? can you add the current output and your desired output? print screen will do :) by the way, try to use `INNER JOIN` :)

Comment: if i removed away the S.Unit = ''. the records in those staff whom do not have a unit, will not be shown out. Inner Join will not works with only S.Unit = U.UnitCode condition. If i placed back my S.unit = '', the records will become duplicated again

Comment: An example output is given above. Thanks

Comment: actually i am confused with your `duplicated records`. what is then duplicated? the whole record or `StaffNumber` only? Sorry. Can you add simple screenshot of the results?

Comment: @Toteski, see the sample output i have created above. Like the Johson record.

Comment: I just updated my answer.. can you try that one? willing to change for some mistakes. its all untested.

Comment: Don't for get to add `DISTINCT` in the SubQuery.

Comment: Sorry. your code works. But it only populate the values in Staff. How can I show the Unit table values like classcode?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, use [OR](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/or.php) instead of ||

Answer (score 1):

```
Select S.*, U.* from Staff S, Unit U where S.Unit='' OR S.Unit IS null OR S.Unit= U.UnitCode;
```

EDITED:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN S.Unit='' THEN S.Unit END AS blankOne, 
CASE WHEN S.Unit= U.UnitCode THEN S.Unit END AS MatchOne
FROM Staff S, Unit U
WHERE S.Unit= U.UnitCode
```

Comment: Hi, great, there's a blank. but when i execute this statement, the blank records will be duplicated with all the staff no

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are after [left join](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#join-op):

```
Select S.*, U.* 
  from Staff S
  left join Unit U 
    on S.Unit= U.UnitCode
```

This will retrieve all staff records and matching records from Unit, if one exists. If not all columns from Unit for this record will be null.